# How does Squirrel add jdbc jars dynamically?

Tags: java, jdbc, squirrel-sql

Java Squirrel is an great sql tool. It supports ALL databases. I checked it. The only thing you need to do is to point to an external jar.

However, in java, a classpath is immutable. How is it possible? Here is the only solution that works [How should I load Jars dynamically at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60764/how-should-i-load-jars-dynamically-at-runtime). However the author says it's hackish

```
try {
    File file = ...
    URL url = file.toURI().toURL();

    URLClassLoader classLoader = (URLClassLoader)ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
    Method method = URLClassLoader.class.getDeclaredMethod("addURL", URL.class);
    method.setAccessible(true);
    method.invoke(classLoader, url);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

How does Squirrel do it? I presume Squirrel is benchmark

Comment: The link doesn't seem to work http://git.code.sf.net/p/squirrel-sql/git squirrel-sql-git

Comment: try here: https://sourceforge.net/p/squirrel-sql/git/ci/master/tree/

Comment: but in general, adding jars at runtime is not "hackish" -- this is one of the core principals of OSGi.  The code snippet you showed above is a bit hacky, although it could be more cleanly done by creating a new URLClassLoader with a parent of the system CL (which does not require relfection and therefore is not "hacky")